# Preventing my Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask, garbage-collection

I have an `activity` which starts an `asynctask`(called WorkerClass) and from the asynctask i add an `BaseAdapter` to my `GridView`:

I start the AsyncTask from my Activity:

```
if(gallery == null || switchScaleMode == true) {
            myWorkerClass = new WorkerClass(myActivity.this, width, scaleButtonText);
            myWorkerClass.execute();
        }
```

Gallery is a drawable List which Shows Image in my gridview. I know it's really bad to put the whole activity context to another class.. But i Need it to get Access to 2 views in the `WorkerClass(AsyncTask)`. So my first question, would it prevent my Memory leak if i just put the 2 views to the `WorkerClass` instead of the whole activity?

**Why do i know i have a Memory Leak inside my App?**

I started Update Heap in the DDMS for my APP-Process and got following results:

**At StartUp till completely loaded:**

[image]

For me this Looks like a hight amount if there is >90% of Memory usage after start..

Now when i rotate my device several times i get this:(**notice:** i only launch the `WorkerClass` and adding the Adapter to the `GridView` one time, at Startup. Because i don't want to recalculate(getting Images and so on) every time user is rotating (time consumpting).

[image]

So, if i rotate my device again and again i get a Out Of Memory exception in the AsyncTask. Even that i only start it once.. (so there must be some Kind of recreation of an object which cause a OOM ??)

What i don't understand is that if i do a GC over the Button `GC`in the DDMS i get:

[image]

So the amount of Memory which is used by my process has increased? But shouldn't the GC releasing used Memory?

**The last Problem:** I tried to work with **MAT** (Memory Analyzer Tool) from eclipse. But this only works after Startup my app in the `DDMS`. If i rotate it several times before taking a `Heap Dump` "Snapshot" eclipse doesn't do anything. No error, but also no Action. Only Thing i noticed is that i can't start `Heap Dump` again with the following error:

```
12-07 15:09:52.739: E/jdwp(1109): Failed sending b-req to debugger: Invalid argument (67536832 of 96983113)
12-07 15:09:53.759: E/jdwp(1109): Failed sending reply to debugger: Try again
```

Please understand that i don't what to make my whole code public. If you tell me specifically what you want to see i'll try my best..

**Update**

So now i got a Heap Dump after some rotates and this is the Output:

[image]

I instantiate EditText and GridView in my Activity and in my `WorkerClass`. Because These are the only two views which i Need in my `WorkerClass` and why i put my `Activity-Context` to the `WorkerClass`.

So will it solve my Problem is if declare and instantiate them only in the Activity and pass them to the `WorkerClass`.

**Update 2**

The DominatorTree:

[image]

Comment: Are you disposing your drawables on rotation? Also when you rotate do you cancle or stop your asynctask?

Comment: @Nazgul Yes after rotate i fit them to the "new" available screensize. I don't cancel the asynctask, but it only takes about 1 second to finish. So if a start rotating the instance of asynctask should be finished!

Comment: @Nazgul I mean i fit them, but i don't resize them! If in Portrait 4 Images fit in one row, after resize i can place 5 Images in one row.

Comment: Working with drawables is tricky. They are like view extensions and hold on to memory if not disposed. I can see that workerClass i probably an instance level property in activity. Try to reduce coupling between activity and asynctask and also dispose of existing drawables in activity/fragment when rotation happens. Also take a heap dump when that 97% is hit. See whats i it.

Comment: @Nazgul Sorry, i don't understand your second sentence. Can you make it clear to me?. Yeah i tried, butas i mentioned in my question i get an error trying to make a heap dump at 97% ;/. Ok i will try, so you mean i should clear my Gallery and instanciate it new after rotate?

Comment: Yes. Try taking dumps at regular intervals. And clear your gallery, dispose drawables and then recreate again on rotation.

Comment: @Nazgul i got it run! Please look my Update and see what `MAT` Shows me.

Comment: Okie the problem is in Gridview and associated EditTexts in the grids. Are you recycling views there? Do you use a Viewholder in the grid view adapter? Check the dominator tree for both the leak suspects in MAT.

Comment: @Nazgul there is no edittext in my grid, the edittext is outside of the grid and provides searching trough the grid. Yes i'm reusing and i have a holder class! I'v updated my question with the DominatorTree. Please MemoryLeaks and MAT are really new to me so i can't bring any know how inside our conversation.. please guide me ..thanks in adavance. If you want we can move this conversation to Chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66360/discussion-between-nazgul-and-mmike).

Comment: drill inside the Edittext node in the dominator tree. See what text property associated with it there....to figure out which ones of Edittexts are these...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after analyzing your dumps it seems like the problem is the textwatchers that have been added to the edittext. Since listeners in an edittext are saved internally in an arraylist they keep getting appended to the list leading to a leak. try to remove or clean all listeners from the edittext before you add new ones. that should fix the leak.